# Can EKS container OS kernel have higher version than host (node) OS kernel?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, linux-kernel, amazon-eks

If an EKS node has Linux kernel version `x.y`, can a container running on the node have a higher version of linux say `x.(y+1)` or `(x+1).z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Containers share the **machine’s OS system kernel** and therefore do not
> require an OS per application, driving higher server efficiencies and
> reducing server and licensing costs

Asserted from [What's container](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container). Thus for your question, your container will have the same version as the host kernel. You can `uname -srm` on the host and exec the same command in the container to confirm.

Comment: So basically the containers don't have a kernel of their own; they just use the kernel of the host operating system. Is that a correct understanding?

Comment: Container **share** the kernel of the host operating system.

Comment: Thanks! This was a very interesting discussion!